# Javascript prototype and call

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm going to add one extra update function on push method, code is below:

```
function update() {
    console.log("update");
}
let method = 'push';
let oldMethod = Array.prototype[method];
Array.prototype[method] = function () {
    update();
    oldMethod.call(this,...arguments);
}
```

Can someone explain why I should use `oldMethod.call(this,...arguments)` rather than `oldMethod()` only?

Comment: `let method = ['push']` should be `let method = 'push'`. There is no need for it to be an array.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it's a typo.

Comment: Well, `oldMethod` would be called without a reference to the right array instance and without the argument values that should be pushed?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't invoke the "real" `.push()` with `.call()`, the value of `this` (the array into which new values are to be pushed) will be unbound and it won't work.